# How to embed Swagger UI into a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I have cloned https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui and copied `dist` folder from it into a Vue project.

[image]

Then I created a new file SwaggerView.vue with the following code:

```js
<template>
  <div class="swagger" id="swagger"></div>
</template>

<script>
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui';
import 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css';

export default {
  name: "Swagger",
  mounted() {
      const spec = require('../path/to/my/spec.json');
      SwaggerUI({
          spec: spec,
          dom_id: '#swagger'
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

But it leads to an error:

> Failed to resolve import "swagger-ui" from
> "src/views/SwaggerView.vue". Does the file exist?

How is it supposed to be done?